# What's the best way to filter an array of objects to only show those objects which were added since the last time it was filtered?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

My first function scrapes my employers site for a list of users who have completed a task and outputs a json file containing the results. The json file is organized as follows:

```
{"Completed":[{"task":"TitleOfTaskAnd01/01/2019", "name":"UsersFullName"},{"task":"TitleOfTaskAnd01/01/2019", "name":"UsersFullName"}...]}
```

My second function uses the aforementioned json file to automatically generate receipts. On calling these two functions again I would like to leave out all of the previously utilized data, and only generate receipts for the tasks that were not in the results of any previous calls, therefore avoiding the generation of duplicates.

I tried to filter the first array by the elements of the second array, however as far as I can tell you cannot compare objects, or even arrays for that matter. Here is the function I tried to adjust to my needs:

```
let myArray = myArray.filter( ( el ) => !toRemove.includes( el ) );
```

I expect that my use case is not too uncommon and there is already a body of experience regarding best practices in this situation. I prefer solutions that use just javascript, so that I can understand how to navigate the situation better in the future. If however you have a library/module solution that is welcomed as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that two objects are never equal (except they are references to the same object). To check for structural equality, you have to manually compare their properties:

```
  myArray.filter(el => !toRemove.some(el2 => el.task === el2.task && el.name === el2.name));
```

While that works, it will be quite slow for a lot of elements as you compare each object of myArray against all objects of toRemove. To improve that, you could generate a unique hash out of the properties and add that hash into a Set:

```
  const hash = obj => JSON.stringify([obj.name, obj.task]);

  const remove = new Set(toRemove.map(hash));

  const result = myArray.filter(el => !remove.has(hash(el)));
```

This will be O(n + m), whereas the previous solutions was O(n * m).